# lirc error when trying to learn ir code

Tags: pi-3, lirc

I've been struggling for a while now to make my raspberry function as a remote control working on infrared. 
 
Although there is a huge number of tutorials for the issue, I seem to run into some trouble that is not mentioned in any tutorial / blog and could use your help.

I've installed lirc successfully and manage to get pulse / space values for the mode2 command.
When I try to use irrecord, raw or not, I can't seem to finish the job;
Specificaly when it comes to generating 2*80 dots I seem to get a few dots, maybe a whole line, and then it exits saying I don't send any IR signals.

It's really frustrating for me since I've been at it for about two weeks now, and havn't find one single tutorial that addresses this problem.
Needless to say I checked the published conf files and none of them is suitable for me.

If there's an easier way, maybe some native python coding to workaround lirc and learn these commands by myself and send them by myself, it would be great. I only need a small number of buttons (currently less than 10).

WOULD GREATLY APPRECIATE ANY HELP / LEAD TO THE RIGHT DIRECTION.

Answer (score 1):

I can offer a non-LIRC alternative to try.

It might work, it might not, but you should be able to find out within half an hour or so (assuming you have a working IR receiver and IR transmitter).

It uses a Python script to record and playback IR codes.

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_irrp_py

It requires my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/download.html) library which may be pre-installed on a recent Raspbian system.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I've installed the pigpio library. Do I need to install that script, too?

Comment: Yes, you then need to sudo pigpiod to start the daemon.  The script will talk to the daemon to control the GPIO.  Then run the script specifying read mode and the IR receiver GPIO.  Depending on the remote control protocol used by your remote it will then work or not.

Comment: OK, so I've done everything as I saw right, and when I've started the script and ran an IR command from the remote, I got the following error:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./irrp.py -r -g 21 -f ir-codes power
Recording
Press key for 'power'
Short code, probably a repeat, try again
Short code, probably a repeat, try again
Short code, probably a repeat, try again
Short code, probably a repeat, try again
Short code, probably a repeat, try again

Any ideas how can I fix that?
Thanks!

Comment: Also when I changed the SHORT variable to 0 it remained the same output.

Comment: That suggests that your remote control is using an unusual protocol (there are hundreds) which is incompatible with my software.  See if you can get a screen shot on a 'scope (or try my [piscope](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html)).